# Split json to elements and return each element to json

Tags: javascript, json

I wanted to know how to split the json content as attached in image [json sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6G45X.png)
, to smaller one, this means return individual json like the following as a result

```
{
"dlg-0093d9ca-b42d-4b3c-9a89-c872000915f6": [
        {
            "utteranceID": 0,
            "speaker": "agent",
            "source": "[F]text[/F]",
            "target": ""
        },
        {
            "utteranceID": 1,
            "speaker": "customer",
            "source": "Hi. I'm trying to buy movie tickets at the AMC Houston 8 in Houston, Texas.",
            "target": ""
        }
    
    ]
}
```

this is currently the piece of code I'm using

```
function modifyJson_test() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("14VzHnGLGefuf8zYnw8HIZpPfEUv19bkX"); //the json is stored to a drive file
  var text = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var json = JSON.parse(text);
  //Logger.log(json[0])
  for (key in json) {
    the_array = json[key];
    var newArr = [key , the_array];
    var newJson = JSON.stringify(newArr, key);
    Logger.log(newJson)
  }
}
```

The output is as below with this code:

```
{
    "dlg-0093d9ca-b42d-4b3c-9a89-c872000915f6", [
        {
            "utteranceID": 0,
            "speaker": "agent",
            "source": "[F]text[/F]",
            "target": ""
        },
        {
            "utteranceID": 1,
            "speaker": "customer",
            "source": "Hi. I'm trying to buy movie tickets at the AMC Houston 8 in Houston, Texas.",
            "target": ""
        }
    
    ]
}
```

Which is not the output that I want to have.
Could you please help to achieve this?

Comment: I can't find the difference between the (desired?) json output above the code snippet and the (undesired?) output below the code snippet ...

Comment: @derpirscher the difference is in the desired output, I have
"dlg-0093d9ca-b42d-4b3c-9a89-c872000915f6" :  [semi-column]
but in the output of the code, I have:
"dlg-0093d9ca-b42d-4b3c-9a89-c872000915f6" , [comma]

Comment: OK, didn't see the comma. But the json below the code snippet is definitively not the ouput of the code above, because thats invalid json if there really is a comma after `"dlg..."` That could only be valid json, if the very first and very last character were opening and closing square  brackets `[]` instead of curly braces `{}`, ie `["dgl...", [{...}, {...} ] ]`

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick, you extract the values in the right way, but then you pack them as an array instead of packing them as an object

```
function modifyJson_test() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("14VzHnGLGefuf8zYnw8HIZpPfEUv19bkX"); 
  var text = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var json = JSON.parse(text);
  //Logger.log(json[0])

  for (key in json) {
    the_array = json[key];
    var newArr = {[key]: the_array};
    var newJson = JSON.stringify(newArr, key);
    Logger.log(newJson)
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks @Keilath, your code did the trick. I have now the desired output which is: `{
"dlg-0093d9ca-b42d-4b3c-9a89-c872000915f6": [
        {
            "utteranceID": 0,
            "speaker": "agent",
            "source": "[F]text[/F]",
            "target": ""
        },
        {
            "utteranceID": 1,
            "speaker": "customer",
            "source": "Hi. I'm trying to buy movie tickets at the AMC Houston 8 in Houston, Texas.",
            "target": ""
        }
    
    ]
}`
@derpirscher this above is the desired output, not the one below the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

That for loop is adding an unnecessary level of complexity to this project, keys in JSON are unique and therefore no looping is required.

```js
function modifyJson_test() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("14VzHnGLGefuf8zYnw8HIZpPfEUv19bkX"); //the json is stored to a drive file
  var text = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var json = JSON.parse(text);
  var newJson = JSON.stringify({[key]: json[key]})
  Logger.log(newJson)
}
```

Comment: thanks @Jacob for this code. The result when running your code is `ReferenceError: key is not defined
modifyJson_test2 @ test.gs:19`

But anyway @Keilath has given the right code for the desired output.

Comment: The same error is returned when the code you provided is run, which means you must have initiated it outside of the scope of the function. If not, based on context, add the line `var key = "dlg-0093d9ca-b42d-4b3c-9a89-c872000915f6"` to the start of the function